# How to install multiple client certificates in ubuntu server?

Tags: php, ssl, ubuntu, ldap

- I have a php script to connect 2 different ldaps servers.
- I learnt that I need to put some configuration on ldap.conf

e.g.

```
BASE dc=a,dc=b,dc=c,dc=d 
URI ldaps://somesite1.com
TLS_REQCERT demand
TLS_CACERT /etc/ssl/certs/1.cert


BASE ou=e,o=f
URI ldaps://somesite1.com
TLS_REQCERT demand 
TLS_CACERT /etc/ssl/certs/2.cert
```

- Because they have 2 different bases, I am not sure how to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

The URLs are the same for both servers?

"[PHP has no method to set a client certificate](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLDAP_Authentication/FAQ#My_LDAP_server_requires_SSL.2FTLS_client_authentication.2C_where_do_I_configure_this.3F)" but the link provides a method for working around this using a single certificate. However this isn't going to work when trying to access both LDAP servers in the same PHP script.

The obvious way to address this would be to run stunnel on the webserver with appropriate configs for each LDAP server (see [this howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/LDAP-Implementation-HOWTO/ssl.html) and the docs on the [stunnel website](http://www.stunnel.org)) listening on different ports for each LDAP server.

Comment: * An example: If I use firefox to visit some SSL sites, I will be prompted with client certificates, so I can decide whether I should trust them. Is server working in the similar way? i.e. Install multiple client certificates, so my server or desktop can connect to different ldaps servers?